# HTML indenting with Perl

Tags: html, perl, indentation

I have a variable (ex. $content) with HTML code (without line breaks - removed before). How to process HTML code with adding TAB indent after each open tag and decrease indent level after each closing tag?

P.S. I don't need external script or programm (like tidy). I need to make this in my own script.

For example:
source content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head>   <body>  <h1>hello!</h1><p>It works!</p></body></html>
```

needed result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello!</h1>
        <p>It works!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an existing parser/"tidy"er, you'll need to do the parsing and tree ouput yourself. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe :) I need to format a **part** of html code with **tab** indents. I've tried tidy but it can't do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
use HTML::HTML5::Parser qw();
use HTML::HTML5::Writer qw();
use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint qw();

print HTML::HTML5::Writer->new(
    start_tags => 'force',
    end_tags => 'force',
)->document(
    XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new_for_html(
        indent_string => "\t"
    )->pretty_print(
        HTML::HTML5::Parser->new->parse_string(
            '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head>   <body>  <h1>hello!</h1><p>It works!</p></body></html>'
        )
    )
);
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello!</h1>
        <p>It works!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He seems pretty insistent on wanting tabs for the indent. So I think you need `indent_string => "\t"`.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html) says that `tidy` won't produce output that contains tabs. But it's simple enough to post-process the output to deal with that.

```
$ tidy -indent foo.html | perl -pe 's|^( +)|"\t" x ((length $1) / 2)|e;'
```

Using an existing tool has to be a far better solution than inventing it yourself. But if you insist then you should, at least, use a pre-written parser like Perl's HTML::Parser.

I should also point out that your specification of the problem seems to be incorrect. You say you want to add a tab after each opening tag. But your sample output doesn't do that for the <title>, <h1> or &p> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Marpa::R2::HTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/module/Marpa-R2) referring to the source of its companion/demo utility [html_fmt](https://metacpan.org/module/html_fmt) to see how to target specific parts of the document for manipulation. I haven't used it and can't try today for want of 5.10 but it looks like it could be a good match.

Answer (score 1):

An option I've used is [CGI::Pretty](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.58/lib/CGI/Pretty.pm).